# How can transform the URLs text inside my code into links without changing their appearance?

Tags: html, css

I want to transform the text URLs into links without changing their appearance, but I really don't find how to do that here.

I tried to put `<a>` but either it transforms everything into links or just hides the part with the target URL.

```
<span class="token selector">.404 Error Page</span><span class="token punctuation">{</span>
  <span class="token property">background</span><span class="token punctuation">:</span><span class="token url"> url:("https://inesmathy.github.io/404-page/index.html")</span><span class="token punctuation">;</span>
<span class="token punctuation">}</span>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/e1byd8sa/) is the link to the code

Comment: HTML and CSS don't have that capability. You need to use a programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `<span>` into `<a>` with `href` like below

```html
<!-- From -->
<span class="token url">url("https://inesmathy.github.io/404-page/index.html")</span>

<!-- To -->
<a class="token url" href="https://inesmathy.github.io/404-page/index.html">url("https://inesmathy.github.io/404-page/index.html")</a>
```

Working example [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/harishk3499/fbsvyton/1/)